# Issue with python os project (auto file organiser)

Tags: python-3.x

I have rearranged my code many times but I can not discover the issue?

```
    import os 
    import shutil

    image_formats = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"]
    audio_formats = ["mp3"]
    video_formats = ["mp4"]
    document_formats = ["txt"]

    files = os.listdir("./")


    for file in files:
    
       if os.path.isfile(file) and file != "shutiling.py":
         ext = (file.split(".")[-1])

         if ext in audio_formats:
             shutil.move(file,"audio/")

         elif ext in image_formats:
             shutil.move(file,"image/")

        elif ext in video_formats:
            shutil.move(file,"video/") 

         elif ext in document_formats:
             shutil.move(file,"document/")
            
         else:
             shutil.move(file,"other/")

     if os.path.exists("audio"):
     None
  else:
     os.mkdir("audio")

  if os.path.exists("image"):
      None
  else:
      os.mkdir("image")

   if os.path.exists("document"):
       None
   else:
       os.mkdir("document")

  if os.path.exists("video"):
      None
   else:
      os.mkdir("video")

  if os.path.exists("other"):
      None
 else:
     os.mkdir("other")
```

I tried putting a time dot sleep function in the program to slow down the program because when I ran it, it turned the folder/dir into a text file, (what I was trying to sort).

Comment: a few remarks : you need to create the folders before moving the files into them  (this mifght actually be the source of your issue). use `os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)` to avoid having to check if the path already exists. Getting the extension of the file would be simpler with the `str.endswith` method : e.g. : `if file.endswith(image_formats): do_something()`. Finally, if the problem persists, please print the return value of `shutil.move` and report it here. This should be the name of the file once it's been moved. That could help figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and what is the exact problem you're facing? Write them in the question please

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is because when the program for example tries to move sound.mp3 to audio/ and the audio directory doesn't exist, your computer will ignore the / and create a new file.

This can be fixed by placing the "for file in files" after creating the directories (audio, image, video, ...). And also using os.path.isdir, instead of os.path.exists. This is because os.path.isdir checks if the path exists, and if it is a directory.

Your changed code will look like this:

```py
import os
import shutil

image_formats = ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif"]
audio_formats = ["mp3"]
video_formats = ["mp4"]
document_formats = ["txt"]

files = os.listdir("./")

if os.path.exists("audio"):
    None
else:
    os.mkdir("audio")

if os.path.exists("image"):
    None
else:
    os.mkdir("image")

if os.path.exists("document"):
    None
else:
    os.mkdir("document")

if os.path.exists("video"):
    None
else:
    os.mkdir("video")

if os.path.exists("other"):
    None
else:
    os.mkdir("other")

for file in files:
    if os.path.isfile(file) and file != "shutiling.py":
        ext = file.split(".")[-1]

        if ext in audio_formats:
            shutil.move(file, "audio/")

        elif ext in image_formats:
            shutil.move(file, "image/")

        elif ext in video_formats:
            shutil.move(file, "video/")

        elif ext in document_formats:
            shutil.move(file, "document/")

        else:
            shutil.move(file, "other/")
```

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).